# Show a video on a webpage with different audio sources

Tags: video-streaming

I have read quite a bunch of responses on stackoverflow but none seems to fit my use case.
I would like to have personalized videos on a simple web page. The video should always be the same but the audio should change with a parameter passed through the url.

I have 1000 audios and 1 video. I could merge audios on videos to make 1000 videos, but I cannot host so much videos.

Here is what I would like to achieve :
exemple.com/?video=1  should show a video with 1.mp3 sound.
exemple.com/?video=2  should show a video with 2.mp3 sound.

A little bit like a video translated in different languages.
Is there a way to host audio and videos and combine them as the webpage is opened ?
Thanks,